# C# application to post on facebook group as regular user

Tags: c#, facebook

I've just developed my first c# app to post on facebook. Currently, I have no problems to post on my wall, but what I want to do is to post on group's wall, but not as admin, but as regular user. When I changed ID to post with group one instead of my profile, I get auth error. It seems I am missing some permissions. Please take a look at my code and tell me what I am missing to post on given group's wall, and again to underline, **I want to post as regular user of the group, not as admin.**

So I use this when I am getting the permissions.

```
private const string ExtendedPermissionsNeeded = "publish_actions";
```

I am using this to generate Login Url

```
private string GenerateLoginUrl()
        {
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

            parameters.client_id = app_id;
            parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
            parameters.response_type = "token";
            parameters.display = "popup";

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExtendedPermissionsNeeded))
                parameters.scope = ExtendedPermissionsNeeded;

            var fb = new FacebookClient();

            Uri loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

            return loginUri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

And finally here is what i am using to post on facebook:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            string accessToken;
            bool authorized;
            if (webBrowser1.Visible)
            {
                var fb = new FacebookClient();

                FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
                if (fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Url, out oauthResult))
                {
                    if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
                    {
                        accessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
                        authorized = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        accessToken = "";
                        authorized = false;
                    }

                    if (authorized)
                    {
                        fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                        dynamic result = fb.Get("me");
                        fb.Post("/100000853192437/feed", new { message = "test " });



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't log into Facebook!", "Login unsuccessful", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With API v2.4, you can not post into regular groups any more as a normal user.

`user_groups` permission has been removed (and will be removed for all apps, whatever API version they are using, on Oct. 6, 2015), and only `user_managed_groups` is available now – and that only gives access (read/write) to the groups the user is an admin of.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/feed#publish
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Comment: I just created test group where I am admin and I can post there through my app even with only "publish_actions" permission granted. So it looks like I will not be able to create my app to post on other groups where users are not admins. I am looking for confirmation of my statement if it's true, or I am wrong and I can somehow make my app to post on group where the user is just member, not admin?

Comment: Yes, only admin users can post to groups via API, normal members can not any more. (Unless it’s an app and game group.)